# Comparing a string with a struct member in C

Tags: c, struct, cs50, strcmp

I am attempting to create a small ticket pricing system. The user inputs the people accompanying them to the theme park as a command line argument (senior/adult/child/student) including themselves (what they are according to that list) and I compare the command line arguments with the struct members named tier - this part will be completed later with pointers to check each one, but until then I'm just attempting to get this lesser version of the completed program to work and cannot seem to. It won't allow me to compare a struct member (string) with a command line argument. I'm finding rectifying this slightly confusing because the error message

> `strcmpare.c:17:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'senior'            if (strcmp(argv[a], senior.tier[a]) == 0)`

isn't yielding any clues as to what I should do. Here's the code so far (I am using the cs50 course and sandbox, thus the cs50.h header file. Apologies in advance, I'm not sure what the equivalent is in C):

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ages
{
    char tier[7];
    int price;
};

void structorganizer(struct ages senior, struct ages adult, struct ages child, struct ages student);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    for (int a = 0; a <= (argc-1); a ++)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[a], senior.tier[a]) == 0)
        {
            printf("no errors");
            return 0;
        }
        printf("scrutinise more");
        return 1;
    }
}

void structorganizer(struct ages senior, struct ages adult, struct ages child, struct ages student)
{
    strcpy(senior.tier, "Senior");
    senior.price = 10;

    strcpy(adult.tier, "Adult");
    adult.price = 30;

    strcpy(child.tier, "Child");
    child.price = 0;

    strcpy (student.tier, "Student");
    student.price = 20;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, `senior` is used without declaration in `main()`. Secondly, `strcpy (student.tier, "Student");` will cause out-of-range access.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the feedback. I now understand the first part of your answer. But I'm not sure I understand why the second part is so. Why would that cause an out-of-range access?

Comment: Because it is writing 8-byte data `{'S', 't', 'u', 'd', 'e', 'n', 't', '\0'}` to an array that has only 7 bytes.

Comment: „Student“ is 7 chars and tier is declared as char(7) but you need one more for the trailing 0.

Comment: @laurens_noone `\0` is called a [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) and it indicates, where the string ends and it needs to be stored in `student.tier` as well.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang and all above, thank you all so much for the clarification. I had no idea you had to include the null terminator in the array dimensions, wow. I'll try this out and see if it works better. Thank you :)

Comment: One small thing about `a <= (argc-1)`. It's easier to read if you use `a < argc` (and more reliable practice generally).

Comment: Also note that the 2nd argument of `strcmp(argv[a], senior.tier[a])` is wrong: if `senior` is `struct ages`, it will pass `char` where `char*` is expected and have high chance to cause Segmentation Fault.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you for the tips :)

Comment: @MikeCAT I don't think I got the notification for this, but thank you for highlighting that part as I've still been having problems with it

Answer (score 0):

> I'm finding rectifying this slightly confusing because the error message isn't yielding any clues as to what I should do.

On the contrary, it actually tells you EXACTLY what to do. That's not always the case with error messages, but here it is. The variable `senior` is not declared, so you need to declare it.

So where should you do that. You seem to want to use `structorganizer` to initialize things. Usually, global variables are a thing you want to avoid and there are certainly better ways of solving this, but just to quickly get things working. Remove all arguments from the function and declare global variables before, and call `structorganizer` first thing in `main` like this:

```
struct ages
{
    char tier[8]; // Changed to 8 because you need one more than the string length
    int price;
};

// Evil global variables, just to make code work with as little
// changes as possible
struct ages senior, adult, ages, child, student;

void structorganizer(); // Init the evil globals

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    structorganizer();

    // Continue as before
```

That should be enough to just get the code working, but you clearly need to spend more time with the basics here. The code you're writing right now is too advanced for you. No shame in trying though :)

There are absolutely cases where it's good to use an initializer function, but I cannot really say that this is one of them. I would declare them in `main` like this:

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    struct ages senior   = { .tier = "Senior",   .price=10 };
    struct ages adult    = { .tier = "Adult",    .price=30 };
    struct ages child    = { .tier = "Child",    .price=0  };
    struct ages student  = { .tier = "Student",  .price=20 };
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the feedback! I'll make the changes you suggested. I was trying to use structorganizer() to initialize everything and set values for them. Is that bad practise? And you mentioned that global variables were a bad idea, could I ask if you would intialize + assign values for everything in main instead? I was attempting to see if I could assign values to each variable's fields without it being in main if it's even possible or wise to do that :/

Comment: @laurens_noone A complete answer to what you are wondering would not fit here in comment section. :)

Comment: Ah, I see haha. Thank you for the tips thus far though :D

Comment: But to put it short. Globals are dangerous but sometimes useful. Beginners should avoid them. And if you want to modify parameters passed to a function, you need to learn about pointers. There are absolutely cases where it's good to use an initializer function, but I cannot really say that this is one of them

Comment: I guess I'll be off to learn more about pointers then :)